# kubectl replace loadbalancer responds with error about duplicate nodePort

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: feature-branches
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-proxy-bot
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I changed the above to add forwarding for port 443 with:

```
        - port: 443
          targetPort: 443
```

However when doing a `kubectl replace...` I get an error of:

> Error from server: error when replacing
> "nginx-bot-proxy-loadbalancer.yaml": duplicate nodePort: {TCP 30054}

I do not understand why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to use `kubectl apply ...`... Strangely it complained about no name being set for the ports (even though I created it the first time with no issue). So I just just updated the values to:

```
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      name: http
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      name: https
```